# parent template is not updating after transitiontoroute() in ember js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

1. List item

I have login controller . After login successful I am calling   controller.transitionToRoute('patients.index') which is my dashboard. Page gets redered but my header menu is not updating . If I try to refresh  page by hitting F5 then my header gets updated.

Thanks in advance.

**My controller:**

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    login: Ember.inject.service('testservice'),
    actions: {
    authenticate: function() { 
    var controller=this; 
         controller.set('login').currentUser=false;
         controller.transitionToRoute('dashboard.index');
       },
    }

});
```

**Dashboard route :**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  authManager: Ember.inject.service('testservice'),
     renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render({
             outlet: 'master',
        });
     },
});
```

**application.hbs handlbar:**

```
<header id="main">
```

```
{{#link-to 'index'}}<img id="logo" src="assets/logo.png"/>{{/link-to}}

<ul id="user">
  <li><a id="user-icon"></a>
    <ul>
      {{#if isUser}}
        <li>{{#link-to 'account.edit'}}Account{{/link-to}}</li>
        <li>{{#link-to 'account.invitation'}}Invite{{/link-to}}</li>

        <li><a {{action 'logout'}}>Logout</a></li>
      {{else}}
        <li><a {{action 'Userlogin'}}>Login</a></li>
      <li>{{isUser}}</li>

      {{/if}}

    </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>

</div>
</header>

<div class="container">
  {{outlet}}
</div>
```

**application controller:**

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    login: Ember.inject.service('testservice'),
    isUser:function() {
       return this.get('login').currentUser;
    }.property('login'),
});
```

Comment: Can you include any relevant code?

Comment: @vikram7 , I have included code. Basically I want to update my application template after login page redirected to dashboard template. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`controller.set('login').currentUser=false;` as well as `return this.get('login').currentUser;` is wrong!

First what is `controller`?
Probably you want to use `Ember.set(this, 'login.currentUser' true)`, or `this.set('login.currentUser', true)`, or `this.get('login').set('currentUser', true)`.

For the get its the same. Usually *never* do `...get(...).something`!
Just do `this.get('login.currentUser')` or `Ember.get('login.currentUser')`.

---

Btw you can rewrite

```
isUser:function() {
   return this.get('login').currentUser;
}.property('login'),
```

with

```
isUser: Ember.computed.alias('login.currentUser'),
```

Comment: sorry I missed to add     var controller=this; in my above controller code. I have updated my code

Comment: @Gopalkrishna still `controller.set('login').currentUser=false;` is wrong! Dont use the `=`!